# Empty document when export string to .tex file

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, export, latex

I am trying to create a simple .tex file:

```
document = """
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
Hello world!
$Hello world!$ %math mode 
\end{document}
"""

file = open("main.tex",'w')
file.write(document) 
file.close
```

It creates a document, named "main.tex" but this document is empty. **Any ideas why and how to fix it?**

Comment: Are you sure that you are looking at the correct main.tex file? If I execute your code, it works.

Comment: @Antje This is weird ! Yes, I changed the name and double-checked, but the file is empty.

Comment: @Antje I am using Jupyter Notebook and Python 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run this code like this, the problem come from:

```
file.close
```

add parenthensis to:

```
file.close
```

which become:

```
file.close()
```

Comment: Thank you so much !! :)) I completely forgot to put the parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

you could try this:

```
Sub Create_Text()

On Error Resume Next
MkDir "C:\Temporal"

On Error GoTo 0

document = "" & _
"\documentclass[12pt]{article}" & _
"\begin{document} " & _
"Hello world! " & _
"$Hello world!$ %math mode " & _
"\end{document}"

Open "C:\Temporal\main.txt" For Append As #1
    Print #1, document & ";"
    Close #1

End Sub
```

I hope this helps!!!

Comment: Thanks. I get: Sub Create_Text() Invalid Syntax